# Browser is not setting cookies after Response.Cookies.Append() - ASP.net core 6 webAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I have this code in my webAPI project:

```cs
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Expires = newRefreshToken.Expires
};

Response.Cookies.Append("someKey", "someVal", cookieOptions);
```

On a following browser response, I get this:

```
set-cookie: someKey=someVal; expires=Thu, 15 Sep 2022 07:02:31 GMT; path=/; httponly
```

But the browser does not set the cookies as seen in the application tab of the dev tools.

How do I make sure that the cookies get set?

Edit: Here is my Program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlite(
        builder.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection").Value
    );
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthRepo, AuthRepo>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
                    builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value)),
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        }
    );
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Could you share your code of the Program.cs?

Comment: I edited the post and added the code of my Program.cs @QingGuo , removed the using statements because it was too long.

Comment: For anyone who has problems setting/updating cookies, in the network tab of dev tools of your browser (im using edge), at the right side of the set cookie header in the request, there is a very small yellow warning sign that tells you what the problem is if you hover your mouse over it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```cs
var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Expires = newRefreshToken.Expires,
    IsEssential = true
};

Response.Cookies.Append("someKey", "someVal", cookieOptions);
```

Comment: Hey, that works and I understand what the problem is. But thank you. I tried it before but it didn't work for some reason. Maybe I should have restarted visual studio or something. If someone reading this wants to know more, it has to do with cookie consent. Setting IsEssential = true means that those checks will be ignored. Here's how to set cookie policy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-6.0 but I have no idea yet how to set cookie consent to true (user accepts non essential cookies) with webAPI.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by setting Secure = true after noticing my debug log was displaying a cookie warning which indicated that by default my cookie's SameSite property was set to "None" and that .NET requires also setting Secure property to "True" to work. Once I did that, the cookie appeared.

```cs
cookieOptions.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
cookieOptions.Secure = true;
```